# Dynamic wizard react

Tags: reactjs

Say I have a bunch of components that look like this:
[image: component description]

I want the following behaviour:

- when on `Component A`, depending on the choice of my radiobutton,
  `Component B` or `Component C` should render when I click the next
  button
- when on `Component B`, I should be able to render `Component A` by pressing the back button.

Currently I have a master component that contains a few things:
- an enum `ComponentName` containing all of the names of my components
- a `Map<string, ReactNode>` that contains a mapping from all of the componentnames to actual component instances.
- a useState hook: `const [currentComponent, setCurrentComponent] = useState<ComponentName>(ComponentName.startComponent)`

Finally, my master component has a `render` function that simply does:
`<>{componentMap.get(currentComponent.toString())}</>`

This *works* but this seems like a very verbose and tedious way of doing things. In order to maintain/change things, I must:
- first work out which constants to change (i.e. the order of the components)
- ensure that the transitions between components are not broken (this is error-prone as I might not test everything manually)

Is there a better way of achieving the same behaviour? I would especially like it if I could declare each of my components independently and not have a master component like I have now.

Edit: There is a question about desired end result. The context of all of this is that this is a wizard that users must go through before submitting something through a form. Each choice the user makes, should change the components that they see so we can ask them the relevant questions. React-router and Link are not relevant to this problem.

Comment: What is the desired end result? Do you need to know wether you went from A to C or from A to B to somewhere else? On first glance I'd say use react-router and combine its <Route> and <Link> components to achieve this type of navigation.

Comment: @timotgl: edited the question to answer your question.

Comment: @Arnad Datta Don't quite understand why you're excluding react-router, it's capable of rendering a component somewhere inside the component tree, it doesn't have to change the entire page. Since you're describing a hypertext-style navigation essentially, it would be an obvious choice. The radio buttons of your answers change the link target of the buttons below. Which component links to which other component can be hard-coded in the components itself. What you described feels tedious because you added a data structure that you don't need. It doesn't help you with preventing broken transitions.